# Gradle build one task start to execute all task

Tags: android, gradle, task

Running one task in gradle (Android) - runs all tasks (clean, etc.) - how to make it run only one single task?

***task testTask() {
dependsOn copyAssets, Debug1
}***

Start this
PS Q:\AndroidProject\mark\android> ./gradlew copyAssets

> Configure project :gg:android
> :android: Q:\AndroidProject\mark\gg\android\build.gradle

> Configure project :gg:awtold
> gg:awt:android: Q:\AndroidProject\mark\gg\awtold\build.gradle

> Configure project :gg:common
> gg:common: Q:\AndroidProject\mark\gg\common\build.gradle

> Configure project :
> sdfasdf   (this print in another task )
> call in CAF ( and this  )
> call removed (and this )

> Task :testTask NO-SOURCE